# Using enumerate within a dictionary comprehension of a nested list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, enumerate

Is there an elegant/pythonic method for creating a dictionary from a nested list with enumerate, that enumerates at the sublist level rather that at the list-of-lists level?

Please consider this example:

```
nested_list = [["ca", "at"], ["li", "if", "fe"], ["ca", "ar"]]
```

I have tried to convert it into a dictionary that looks like this:

```
# Desired output.
# {'ca': 0, 'at': 1, 'li': 2, 'if': 3, 'fe': 4, 'ar': 5}
```

Here is my best attempt, but it appears to enumerate the list at the upper level and overwrite the value for duplicate keys - which is undesirable.

```
item_dict = {item: i for i, item in enumerate(nested_list) for item in item}
# Current output.
# {'ca': 2, 'at': 0, 'li': 1, 'if': 1, 'fe': 1, 'ar': 2}
```

Am I better off splitting this task into an un-nesting step, and then a dictionary comprehension step?

All insight is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved it, but it's quite ugly...

```
{key: i for i, key in enumerate(set([item for item in nested_list for item in item]))}
# Output.
{'if': 0, 'at': 1, 'fe': 2, 'li': 3, 'ca': 4, 'ar': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.chain`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain

nested_list = [["ca", "at"], ["li", "if", "fe"], ["ca", "ar"]]
result = {}
c = 0
for i in chain.from_iterable(nested_list):
    if i not in result:
        result[i] = c
        c += 1
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'ca': 0, 'at': 1, 'li': 2, 'if': 3, 'fe': 4, 'ar': 5}
```